# sys.argv[1][-4:] script meaning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am actually learning python in deep and saw someone's code with this kind of argument. since I've never seen this before, I was wondering if someone could help me to better understand how it works.

Here is the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   if sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.dfa':
      print("UNEXPECTED INPUT FILE FORMAT\n")
      sys.exit()
   dfa = DFA()
   inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
   inputstring = inputfile.read().split('\n\n');
```

Comment: Look up the `sys.argv` documentation and list slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever running a Python program, `sys.argv` is automatically a list of strings representing the arguments mentioned when running the program.

Using `sys.argv[1]` is therefore the same as looking at the first element of a list, and more precisely the first argument provided when running the Python program. From how Python works, it will always be a string.

So if in script you were to do:

```
python helloworld.py file1.txt file2.jpg
```

And your program contained `sys.argv[1]`, you could see:

```
print(sys.argv[1])

# > "file1.txt"
```

Now, since `sys.argv[1]` is a string, doing sys.argv[1][-4:] is just looking at the four last characters of the string contained in `sys.argv[1]`, so you would have:

```
print(sys.argv[1][-4:])

# > ".txt"
```

So to sum it up, all your code does is checking that the extension of the file mentioned in the first argument when running your program is .dfa, or, in other words, that the file name that you mentioned as first argument ends with `".dfa"`.